"Connection deactivated" error popping up every minute or so in Kubuntu
I just installed Kubuntu 23.10 on a new desktop PC I built, which uses an AX210NGW DTK M.2 wifi/bluetooth card:
e4:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 381, IOMMU group 15
Memory at ba300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

The internet seems to be somewhat working (after all, I'm here using it right now), but at least once a minute I have two "Network Management" error notifications that pop up in KDE that say
"Connection Wired Connection 3 deactivated" and "Wired Interface e2x52e8ae7d39d1: IP configuration was unavailable".
I checked the logs in /var/log/dmesg and saw that there were a ton of error messages in there that look like this:
[   48.918737] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   49.073619] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   49.073640] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   49.073652] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   49.073668] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0[   48.366248] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   48.366790] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 3016002 usecs
[   48.366871] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[   48.394808] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 27321 usecs
[   48.394824] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[   48.395806] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0041-0041.ddc
[   48.404669] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[   48.409660] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: No support for BT device in ACPI firmware
[   48.415854] kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2023.28 buildtype 1 build 68350
[   48.451092] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[   48.451185] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   48.451199] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[   48.451216] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 83.e8f84e98.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-83.ucode
[   48.451234] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[   48.451250] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[   48.451264] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[   48.451278] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x004DC410 | branchlink2
[   48.451291] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x004D233E | interruptlink1
[   48.451304] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x004D233E | interruptlink2
[   48.451317] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00016DBE | data1
[   48.451329] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000010 | data2
[   48.451342] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[   48.451354] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x002FB7D5 | beacon time
[   48.451367] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00110ECE | tsf low
[   48.451379] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[   48.451391] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[   48.451403] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00124E63 | time gp2
[   48.451416] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[   48.451430] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000053 | uCode version major
[   48.451444] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xE8F84E98 | uCode version minor
[   48.451458] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000420 | hw version
[   48.451471] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00C80002 | board version
[   48.451484] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x80A3FC04 | hcmd
[   48.451496] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[   48.451508] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[   48.451519] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[   48.451531] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00C3000C | isr3
[   48.451543] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[   48.451555] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x001D0103 | last cmd Id
[   48.451567] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00016DBE | wait_event
[   48.451580] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[   48.451593] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[   48.451606] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[   48.451619] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00001800 | l2p_addr_match
[   48.451632] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[   48.451645] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[   48.451920] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x0000406C | flow_handler
[   48.452161] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[   48.452279] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[   48.452388] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x2010190E | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[   48.452499] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[   48.452605] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x8046DA58 | umac branchlink2
[   48.452708] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xC00814E0 | umac interruptlink1
[   48.452810] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[   48.452911] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x0101F71C | umac data1
[   48.453008] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[   48.453104] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[   48.453197] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000053 | umac major
[   48.453288] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xE8F84E98 | umac minor
[   48.453378] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00124E5C | frame pointer
[   48.453471] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0xC0886BE0 | stack pointer
[   48.453560] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x0025010D | last host cmd
[   48.453648] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[   48.453746] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[   48.453835] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[   48.453933] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x000080B7 | IML/ROM data1
[   48.454032] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000090 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[   48.454128] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[   48.454219] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[   48.454312] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[   48.454406] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   48.454501] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[   48.454595] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000002 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[   48.454691] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[   48.454788] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[   48.454883] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[   48.454978] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   48.455075] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[   48.455176] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[   48.455275] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[   48.455372] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00080009 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[   48.455469] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[   48.455567] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x00440007 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[   48.455665] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: 0x000000E6 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[   48.455770] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x8048da0c
[   48.455870] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[   48.456070] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[   48.456074] kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[   48.492624] kernel: Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[   48.704814] kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   48.718674] kernel: NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[   48.918737] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[   49.073619] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[   49.073640] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[   49.073652] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[   49.073668] kernel: iwlwifi 0000:e4:00.0: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0

Does anyone know what is causing these errors? It is very annoying, and happens often multiple times per minute, and is causing downloads etc to fail.
I am happy to provide any other information that is helpful to debug.

I'm sorry, I just updated my post to clarify that I am using Ubuntu 23.10
